# Laravel Mix before commit

Tags: laravel, git, npm, githooks, laravel-mix

So, there is a tool Laravel Mix which could be run via npm command like `npm mix dev` or `npm mix prod`.

Locally I need styles and scripts to be compiled but not minified. So I have to run `npm mix dev`. But I need to commit only minified versions of such files. And it's not an option to have both versions in a repository - it has to be only minified.

Is there an option so I can use development files locally but before I make a commit they will be minified? And after commit - unmified again (with `npm mix dev`)

Comment: You shouldn't generally commit generated files - commit _source code_ and have the generated files... generated, as part of the build process.

Comment: I wouldn't put generated files on source control but if you really want to you can probably accomplish this with [Husky](https://www.npmjs.com/package/husky)